# BigQuery as a subscriber to multiple Pub/Sub topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, subscription, subscribe

I've a question, can I create multiple pub/sub subscriptions to the same BigQuery table?

I'm asking because I wanna handle a massive load of data ingestion, and 1 topic may not be satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can point different subscriptions on different topics to the same BigQuery table. Note that Pub/Sub is designed to scale to 10s of GB/s, so a single topic may be sufficient.

Comment: according to documentation, a pub/sub subcription to BigQuery throughput is equal to 140 MB/S not in 10s of GB/s
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas

check "Push and BigQuery subscriber throughput per region"


or Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: That's the default quota. As stated in the documentation "You can request increases to quotas." Even if you were to use multiple topics/subscriptions in the same project, you'd need to request an increase in quota as the quota limits are per project, not per resource.